# Docker Compose Wordpress Plugin não Instala: Connection refused

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker, composer, mariadb

Estou tentando criar uma aplicação em wordpress, através do docker, porém os plug-ins não estão conseguindo ser instalados:

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
    mysql:
        image: mariadb
        ports:
            - "3260:3260"
        volumes:
            - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

    wordpress:
        image: wordpress
        ports:
            - "2000:80"
        volumes:
            - ./wordpress_data:/var/www/html
        environment:
            WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: example
        depends_on:
            - mysql
        links:
            - mysql

volumes:
    mysql_data:
    wordpress_data:
```

Ao abrir o localhost:2000, e inserir todas informações necessárias, no menu de intalação de plug-ins eu recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
Installing Plugin: WPBakery Visual Composer
Baixando pacote de instalação a partir de http://localhost:2000/wp-content/themes/altius/fastwp/plugins/js_composer.zip…

Falha no download. cURL error 7: Failed to connect to localhost port 2000: Connection refused
```

Comment: Ele está tentando baixar o pacote de dentro do seu próprio container, e se o mesmo não possui esse caminho, ou esse plugin, o curl não vai funcionar. Tente instalar a versão mais recente do PHP no seu docker compose. Me informe o resultado.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress não é tão esperto para saber que a url dele é diferente da url do request. Assim você deve usar ambas na mesma porta. Se para teu wordpress a porta do apache é a 80, no container exponha a porta 80 também e use-a.